# Will discharging work if the grounding chassis isn't connected to the mains or otherwise grounded?

Tags: ground, repair, crt

Suppose you have a CRT screen and you want to dismantle it for whatever reason. The high-voltage anode needs to be grounded in order to avoid the risk of electrocution. The metal grounding chassis of that RCT screen won't work unless it itself is grounded which it isn't if it isn't connected to grounded mains or grounded otherwise. Am I understanding this correctly?

It made me wonder after watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdFIi-ZF-6M&t=102s . Am I missing something here? Is that really a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the only(!) correct way of doing that. The CRT itself acts like a plate capacitor (and a very good one at that). The charge is stored between the inner parts of the CRT and its outer conductive coating - not between the CRT and earth. If you short the inside of the CRT (via the anode cap) against its outside (via the various grounding strips connecting to the outside of the CRT), it'll get discharged just fine.

If you instead shorted the CRT's anode against earth, but not against the metal chassis of the monitor, it would **not** get discharged. The monitor's chassis instead would be at a very large negative voltage, which might potentially be quite dangerous.

Comment: Does the "(!)" imply there is no other correct way of doing this?

Comment: the earth gnd connection is irrelevant, while the bridge between CRT and chassis 0V is what counts (!)

Comment: Yes, there is no other correct way of doing this. Tony already explained the reason for this - the connection to ground is irrelevant for discharging the CRT.

Answer (score 3):

The important point is that the HV terminal is high-voltage relative to the chassis (ground), not the Earth. The technician is discharging any voltage in the internal HV circuit.

Technically / ideally, if the device is not connected to mains earth/ground then you can touch any one point inside without a shock. (This is a bit light the bird on the high-voltage line not being electrocuted.) With such a large chassis exposed it would be difficult to work safely on the HV circuit if it was not discharged.